# Mongodb using db.help() on a particular db command

Tags: mongodb

When I type db.help()
It returns

```
DB methods:
        db.addUser(username, password[, readOnly=false])
        db.auth(username, password)
...
...
        db.printShardingStatus()
...
...
        db.fsyncLock() flush data to disk and lock server for backups
        db.fsyncUnock() unlocks server following a db.fsyncLock()
```

I'd like to find out how to get more detailed help for the particular command. The problem was with the printShardingStatus as it returned "too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to print"

```
mongos> db.printShardingStatus()
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: { "_id" : 1, "version" : 3 }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "localhost:10001" }
        {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "localhost:10002" }
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
        {  "_id" : "dbTest",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
                dbTest.things chunks:
                                shard0001       12
                                shard0000       19
                        too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to for
ce print
```

I found that for that particular command I can specify boolean parameter

```
db.printShardingStatus(true)
```

which wasn't shown using db.help().

Answer (score 1):

One way to find our more about a command is to call it without the parentheses to see the javascript :)

```
rs:PRIMARY> db.printShardingStatus
function (verbose) {
    printShardingStatus(this.getSiblingDB("config"), verbose);
}
rs:PRIMARY
```

> 